# Hiding area under transparent shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I'm fairly new to Illustrator and am trying to make a simple cityscape design in it for a tshirt. I need the buildings to be transparent and am trying to overlap them, but I dont know how to hide everything behind a transparent shape. Here's a picture to show what I'm talking about: [image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you can't fill the shapes with white? Realize in printing, even silk screening t-shirts, white = transparent.

Comment: Can you elaborate further your problems I can't understand it clearly? Anyways when you want to hide those things under the building design you can sent it to the back or you can use pathfinder tools to make it more precise

Comment: @Scott even so you can knockout the white

Answer (score 2):

If the two buildings are separate objects:
Put the big building on layer 3.
Put the small building on layer 1.
On layer 2, create a white block with the same shape of the big building.
If you send a copy of the .ai file (version cs5 is preferable), i can do it for you and send it back. :)

Comment: While the offer to do the work for the Asker is great in the spirits of helpfulness, we prefer you'd not. It carries the risk of this site devolving into a place of questions 'I need this fx done, plz gimme teh filez', but it also clashes with out intention to *teach* rather than to help. Give someone a fish and they have food for a day; teach them fishing and they have food for a lifetime. :)